# Android Widget framelayout - fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Can android widget's frame layout be assigned with android fragment?
Will the tab fragment be loaded in app widget?

Answer (score 2):

> Can android widget's frame layout be assigned with android fragment?

No.

> Will the tab fragment be loaded in app widget?

No. Neither tabs nor fragments are supported in app widgets. You can see the roster of what is supported in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).